# Modify VS 2012 C++ header template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When I create a new class in VS 2012, the header will look like this:

```
#pragma once
```

How can I change the default to look like:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

...


#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tsyyf0yh.aspx

Basically make a .h as you want it to appear. Save it as a template.

Make sure to select item template not project template.

You can find it when you select new item and visual c++.